# How to share files from my GCP project to my company's Google Workspace?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm uploading Google Sheets to my GCP project's Google Drive (using CLI utility).
Now - my and my team need to access this google sheet under our Google Workspace.
I do have a link to this google sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/......), but obviously, I don't have access.
How I should 'connect' my company's GCP project and Google Workspace?

Thanks, Vitaly

Comment: To properly address your question, are you using a service account Drive storage to upload these files?

Comment: Yes, service account. 
After some investigation, I think, the simplest solution will be to use my company's Google credentials instead of this account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a user in your domain is a better option. Since service accounts don’t belong to your domain, transferring ownership of these files to your organization won’t be possible as outlined in this Help Center article [Make someone else the owner of your file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892). What you could do instead is make a copy of this file into your domain. To make sure you make the best decision I will mention all available options.

Keep in mind that user authentication with OAuth 2.0 is subject to user/admin token revocation and expiration under many different circumstances, while service account credentials are not. See what can cause a token to become invalid in this documentation article [Refresh token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration).

You could adjust the usage of this service account and either create a permission to modify these files to some users in your organization or transfer the files to a Shared drive (if your Google Workspace subscription includes it). Keep in mind that service accounts have only 15 GB of storage for Google Drive so at some point the service account will run out of storage and files won’t be editable again, moreover there are no options to restore service accounts or audit its usage.

Ideally you can configure domain-wide delegation for this service account and with code impersonate any user in your domain if that's your use case and create and modify files as that user. This is highly recommended as all the activity will be bound to your organization.

Starting from this Python quick start as a example [Drive API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) to impersonate users in your domain you will need to replace the part of the code where user credentials are obtained for an equivalent code where service account credentials are used and a user is impersonated, leaving it as it is will make the code request user authentication as you considered.

Replace this:

```
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

With this:

```
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'serviceaccountcredentials.json'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes= SCOPES)
    delegated_creds = credentials.with_subject("user@domain.com")
```